# Where should I write the if condition for a dynamic variable in Anylogic?

Tags: variables, dynamic, system, modeling, anylogic

I have to write the following condition for a dynamic variable in Anylogic: "When milling on order plus milling inventory is less than milling reordering point, then milling placed is milling to order; otherwise, it is zero" but I don't know in what way should I go.
[Variable Assignment Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYAoJ.png)

Comment: Okay, so I think there are two parts to the question:
 1. What is the syntax for the code to reflect what you are trying to model
 2. Where in AnyLogic (in which field) you should write it

To be able to answer we need more details. Where are you using this variable? Is it in a DES source? In an Agent event? etc.

Comment: When you say dynamic, it means it will be constantly updating. But do you need it updated every second? Or do you need to update right before placing an order? I would assume the 2nd option. So if we know how your model is designed, we can guide you on where your code should be placed and accordingly what syntax to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax 1 (if written in a dynamic field directly):**

```
(milling on order) + (milling inventory) < (milling reordering point) ? (milling to order) : 0
```

**Syntax 2 (if written as code):**

```
if( (milling on order) + (milling inventory) < (milling reordering point) )
milling placed = milling to order;
else
milling placed = 0;
```